# Access axios response data in created function - Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Fetching categories from API, saving it's response in data variable `categories`, then trying to use response data in `mounted ()`:

```
data () {
  return {
    categories: {}
  }
}

created () {
  this.fetchCategories()
  this.showArticles(this.categories[0].id)
}

methods: {
  fetchCategories () {
    return axios.get(globalConfig.FAQCATS_URL)
      .then((resp) => {
        this.categories = resp.data
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
}
```

But getting an error: `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. I guess axios's promise is async, that's why i can't use it's reponse inside `created` or `mounted`. How can i access it's response correctly?

Purpose of my actions, is to set default category on a page load, so page won't be empty, because i'm not showing any items, if category is not chosen.

`showArticles` method:

```
showArticles (id) {
  return axios.get(globalConfig.FAQCATS_URL + '/' + id + '/articles')
    .then((resp) => {
      this.articles = resp.data
      // console.log(resp)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: When and how is `fetchCategories` called? Why do you want to do `this.showArticles(this.categories[0].id)` in `create` when   `fetchCategories` wasn't most likely called at that time. Please show a minimal, complete, code snipped that allows to understand the code flow.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add `fetchCategories()` call. Added now

Comment: Then wait for the promise returned by `fetchCategories` `this.fetchCategories().then(() => this.showArticles(this.categories[0].id))`.

Comment: That `this.showArticles(this.categories[0].id)` looks really suspicious and looks like you try to solve something in a way how you should not solve it in vue.

Comment: @t.niese, i'm setting a default category this way, because id's can be changed.

Comment: Do you mind sharing what `showArticles` does? I agree that there might be a better way to do this than that.

Comment: Added `showArticles`. Please, tell, if you have a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to wait for the Promise returned by `fetchCategories` to resolve using `.then`:

```
this.fetchCategories()
    .then(() => this.showArticles(this.categories[0].id))
```

Or if you can use `await`/`async`:

```
async created () {
  await this.fetchCategories()
  this.showArticles(this.categories[0].id)
}
```

But you probably want to use `watch`:

```
data () {
  return {
    categories: null
  }
}

watch: {
  categories( newList, oldList ) {
     if( !oldList ) {
        // only call showArticles if categories was not et before
        this.showArticles(this.categories[0].id)
     }
  }
} 

created () {
  this.fetchCategories()
}
```

Comment: Isn't a `watch` is overkill for my task? Async/Await looks elegant for me, any drawbacks using this?

Comment: @AlexanderKim Depends, if what you do is do initialy call `this.showArticles` with `this.categories[0].id`  if `categories` was set the first time, then I would use `watch` because it is self explaining. And if you later look at you code and do some refactoring, maybe you decide to do `fetchCategories` at another place using e.g. store like vuex, then `watch` can stay the same and you would only remove your `created`.

Comment: @AlexanderKim or with in other words with `watch` the call `this.showArticles` is driven by the actual event why you want to call `this.showArticles`. With `this.fetchCategories().then( ... )` it is called by your foreseen event that you expect that it will happen. So with `this.fetchCategories().then( ... )`, you would need to have the knowledge that it will indeed change `this.categories`.

Answer (score 0):

`Create` function created before the mounted and methods, so in the first, you can use `mounted` instead `create` second you can call the  API in the `Created` instead `methods` and then store the response in the store function because of you don't access to `data variable` before mounted.

```
data () {
  return {
    categories: {}
  }
}

mounted() {
  this.fetchCategories()
}

methods: {
  fetchCategories () {
    return axios.get(globalConfig.FAQCATS_URL)
      .then((resp) => {
        this.categories = resp.data;
        this.showArticles(this.categories[0].id)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
    }
```